# Upload Local File Using Django Views/URLs

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am currently working on a project where two users can send each other files. Normally this is not that big of an issue as I would just create a form in html. However, I am hoping to use URLs for a few key functions, mainly retrieving and sending files.

Retrieving files is pretty simple, however uploading files using the URL is where I am encountering the problem. Here is what my `views.py` looks like:

```
def send_message(request, sender_id, receiver_id, file_path):
    sender_profile = UserProfile.objects.get(id=sender_id)
    receiver_profile = UserProfile.objects.get(id=receiver_id)

    message = Message.objects.create(sender=sender_profile,
                                     receiver=receiver_profile,
                                     audio=file_path)
    message.save()
```

and here is my `urls.py`:

```
path('api/send-message/<int:sender_id>/<int:receiver_id>/<str:file_path>', api.send_message),
```

The problem here is that I cant just pass though a files location to be uploaded in the url.

I'm a bit of a beginner, but I'm guessing this might be a bit unconventional. The reason I'm doing it this way is because I'm hoping to use the URLs to send and receive data from an Electron/JS desktop application I'm working on. I've looked into the Django REST framework and it's a bit heavy for what I'm hoping to do.

Any ideas on how this can be accomplished? Thanks

Comment: What is `file_path` and where is the file supposed to be coming from?

Comment: `file_path` is a file on the users computer that they upload. However, I want to do this without a form.

Comment: You can't do that... there is no way for Django to access data on a user's machine without using some sort of file upload mechanism. This is a basic security measure enforced by web clients.